# om.next: how to have multiple components that use the reconciler

Tags: clojurescript, om, om.next

I'm new to om.next (and to clojurescript), and I have the following question. I can only get the root component to be invoked with the reconciler (i.e. have its query method invoked); every other component seems to need to be invoked with props and with `om/factory`. I think I'm missing something.

I am attempting to create a todo list app (100 points for originality!), with a filter to show completed/incomplete/all items. If my `TodoList` component is the root component, I can invoke it with query: `[:todos]` with no problem. I'd like to have a different root component, and also have a `Filter` component that goes through the reconciler.

Possible options I can see:

- have multiple om/add-root! calls (this prevents us from having nested components that use the reconciler, and is not the pattern that I see in tutorials)
- wrap everything in a global component and pass state down through props. But the examples make read a multimethod, which doesn't jive with this approach.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The concept behind Om Next (and others such as reframe) is that there is one source of truth - your app state. With Om Next the UI of your application is made up of one (upside down) component tree. During rendering your app state is loaded into your `Root` component by Om Next interpreting its static query. This app state is received as 'props'. It is your job to pick these props apart and hand 'sub props' down the rest of the tree. You do this in the `render` method of each of your components.

So your second option is the way to go. `read`s are related to keywords that are in your static component queries. If you make sure that your state is in *default db format*, then in fact every `read` can be implemented the same way, making use of `db->tree`. Having a *global component* and making every `read` a multimethod are unrelated concepts, and thus not incompatible. In fact having both is quite idiomatic.

There are ToDo application examples already that you may wish to look at for reference: [here](https://github.com/swannodette/om-next-demo) and [here](https://github.com/untangled-web/untangled-todomvc).

One thing to note is that your `Root` component query will use joins to *include* the other components, so your query `[:todos]` does not look right to me. Something like `[{:todos (om/get-query TodoList)}]` would be better :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already please take a look at [Components, Identity & Normalization · omcljs/om Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components,-Identity-&-Normalization). This tutorial shows how to organize a multi-component application under a single root - and it should also make clear how `read`, `mutate`, `Ident`, `IQuery`, etc. are being used by each *individual* component to coordinate interaction with the *one-and-only* app state via the reconciler. The app-state is basically the application's database - using nested data structures inside a single [Map](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Maps).

React applications typically only have a single root component - if there *are* multiple roots they are typically organized by routes, i.e. one root per route (see also [Top-level React Components — Medium](https://medium.com/@tarkus/top-level-react-components-19ac81dfec5f#.uc371olrk)).

Also: [Om/Next: The Reconciler — Medium](https://medium.com/@kovasb/om-next-the-reconciler-af26f02a6fb4#.gwsl40ba3)